# Jest equivalent to RSpec lazy evaluated variables (let)?

Tags: javascript, testing, ecmascript-6, jestjs

In rspec you can do something like this:

```
let(:input) { 'foo' }
before_each do
   setup_some_thing(input)
end

context 'when input is bar do
  let(:input) { 'bar' }
  it 'does something different' do
  end
end

context 'when input is baz do
  let(:input) { 'baz' }
  it 'does something else different' do
  end
end
```

This allows you to define a method call or instantiation of a large object as a sum of its smaller parts. You can then override those individual small parts inside different contexts. The idea being that you create a happy path before each test, and then specify deviations from the happy path within your context blocks.

Unfortunately, I can't seem to do this with Jest. I've tried the following:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  let input = 'foo';
  beforeEach(() => {
    setupSomeThing(input);
  });

  describe('when input is bar', () => {
    input = 'bar';
    it('does something different', () => {

    });
  });

  describe('when input is baz', () => {
    input = 'baz';
    it('does something different', () => {

    });
  });
});
```

Because jest executes every describe block before running any specific describe block, input is always 'baz'. Does anyone know a work around, or a way to get the rspec behavior?

Thanks in advance!

#### Update

You can get similar behavior (albeit without lazy evaluation) using beforeAll.

```
beforeEach(() => {
  let input = 'foo';
  beforeEach(() => {
    setupSomeThing(input);
  });

  describe('when input is bar', () => {
    beforeAll(() => {
     input = 'bar';
    });

    it('does something different', () => {

    });
  });

  describe('when input is baz', () => {
    beforeAll(() => {
     input = 'baz';
    });        

    it('does something different', () => {

    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Put the assignment inside the `it`?

Comment: Or use an immutable structure that you pass (implicitly or explicitly) into your tests, instead of relying on `let `

Comment: Also take a look at https://github.com/stalniy/bdd-lazy-var

Comment: Little late to the game, but that looks amazing. Going to use it as soon as I get a chance, thanks!

Comment: it's worth noting that in the updated technique, if you removed the last `beforeAll` that sets `input` to 'baz', then the `input` will be 'bar', not 'foo' (which one might expect).

Comment: The outer `beforeEach` should be `describe`.

Comment: Looks like there's some js testing misunderstanding going on. You can always call your setupSomeThing(...) from within your test, or do an Object.assign when you want to merge objects.

Comment: I agree. I'm not sure what's at stake in this question.

Comment: It's been a while since I've messed with this. What's at stake is code duplication. With the rspec let way of doing things, you can avoid calling setupSomeThing in every single "it" block. Or separate before blocks in each describe block. With one function, it's somewhat trivial to do without the rspec-style lets. But if the setup requires 8 different inputs, some of which need to change between contexts and some that don't, it's much easier to just have that setup code once in a before block that uses "let" variables that are changed depending on the context.

Comment: It ends up cleaning up your test code substantially. The `let`s act as declarative control switches to hit different branches of the code under test. This reduces the test to clean blocks specifying what the switches are (essentially specifying what logical branches to go through) followed by a set of `it` blocks describing all of the things that should happen given that set of `let`s.

Comment: For the sake of future readers of this highly upvoted question, I suggest you move the conclusion section to an answer.

Comment: @Noah! If I could give you bounty for answering your own question, I would. Thank you so much for posting this. It's the _exact_ question I had, coming from a heavy Rails/RSpec background. I found my Jest tests to be repetitive without an equivalent `subject` or `let` and it was driving me mad. I had all but given up until I found your post and your simple, but clever solution of using `beforeAll`, which non-intuitively runs before the parent `beforeEach`. Regardless, well done and thank you once again.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The best solutions I've found have been libraries like

https://github.com/stalniy/bdd-lazy-var

and

https://github.com/tatyshev/given2

If you don't want to introduce a dependency, you can get similar behavior (albeit without lazy evaluation) by doing something like this:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  let input = 'foo';
  beforeEach(() => {
    setupSomeThing(input);
  });

  describe('when input is bar', () => {
    beforeAll(() => {
     input = 'bar';
    });

    it('does something different', () => {

    });
  });

  describe('when input is baz', () => {
    beforeAll(() => {
     input = 'baz';
    });        

    it('does something different', () => {

    });
  });
});
```

Comment: My biggest peeve is losing variable typing that helps autocomplete. You can add js docs to help give documented typing which may help some. ie `/** @type {string} */` unfortunately this may not work with complex typing such as generics :(

Answer (score 4):

### Use a `beforeAll` to set variables in a parent `beforeEach`.

*Building on @Noah's own answer, I thought I would share our final solution with using `this` as well.*

```js
describe( "Logging in", () => { 
  beforeEach( () => login( this.password ) ); // Steps are same for all so re-use but use different password.

  describe( "when password is incorrect", () => {
    beforeAll( () => this.password = "INCORRECT PASSWORD" );

    it( "doesn't log in.", () => {
      // Your assertion(s).
    } );
  } );

  describe( "when password is correct", () => {
    beforeAll( () => this.password = "CORRECT PASSWORD" );

    it( "logs in successfully.", () => {
      // Your assertion(s).
    } );
  } );
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

I’ve recently created my own library similar to the other ones mentioned here to achieve this exact purpose, as I felt both the other ones mentioned here had a few shortcomings. Check it out!

https://github.com/enova/givens

The only difference between this and Rspec is that it doesn’t actually put the variable on the scope, instead having you access it on the given function (which is why I didn’t want to use bdd-lazy-var)

The advantage of this library over given2 is that it fully supports caching across beforeEach and afterEach calls for a given test. If you have to interact with a lazily declared variable in a beforeEach block to do some set up, that set up will be preserved for the actual test, and the afterEach block after, before being cleared for the next test.

Answer (score 0):

There is an npm module dedicated to that: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-rspec-style

The code would look like

```
describe('Hoge', () => {
  lazy('hoge', () =>
    new Hoge({ value: lazy('value') })
  )

  describe('#call', () => {
    subject(() =>
      lazy('hoge').call()
    )

    lazy('value', () =>
      'hoge-value'
    )

    it('Return value', () => {
      expect(subject()).toEqual('hoge-vale')
    })

    ...
```